# append an image to ckeditor via jquery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor to add posts at a site:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea>
```

and I want to append some text or image to the textarea of it when I click at a button via jquery.

I tried this but not worked:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
  img = "<img src='http://localhost/sdn/files/uploads/1368647314.png'/>'";
  $(".cke_editable").append(img); // also I tried:  $("#editor1").append(img);
});
});
</script>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CKEditor API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
  img = "<img src='http://localhost/sdn/files/uploads/1368647314.png'/>'";
  CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml(img);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it solves my problem with image insertation!

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
  img = "<img src='http://localhost/sdn/files/uploads/1368647314.png'/>'";
  CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(img);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var img=$("<img src='http://localhost/sdn/files/uploads/1368647314.png'/>");
```

It looks like you've got an extra quote in there and I think you might need to make it a jquery object. Make sure to use `var` keyword to keep the variable local.