# How to manage onclick event of a CKEditor custom plugin in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I want to create a custom plugin for CKEditor 5 in react.js like what is done in:

*StackOverFlow question:* [CKEditor 5 insert image by external url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642683/ckeditor-5-insert-image-by-external-url)

*CKEditor documentation:* [Creating a simple plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/creating-simple-plugin.html)

In the above examples when the plugin is clicked the code below executes and user enters the image URL:

```
const imageUrl = prompt( 'Image URL' );
```

which is in `init()` method of the plugin class. But what I'm intending to do is:

When the custom plugin is clicked I want a react component to open, then user selects an image and the URL of the selected image gets passed to CKEditor to be inserted. I've read lots of articles and Stackoverflow Q&As but still I don't know how to manage the click event of the plugin in React to open the component and pass the URL to CKEditor.

P.S: I'm using a build of CKEditor which I'm customizing and building it myself (like [this article](https://medium.com/@jacobtamus/ckeditor5-custom-react-editor-tutorial-a9e91aab9d16)). So I'm NOT integrating CKEditor into my project which is another option of using it in React.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the exact solution. Instead, I ended up using a button next to CKEditor in order to insert images in a way that the whole process of inserting is under control of React.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";

const MyEditor = () => {
  const [editorInstance, setEditorInstance] = useState("");
  const insertImage = () => {
    const imageUrl = prompt("Image URL"); //the process of getting the image's url in React
                                          //here, it is only a prompt but it could be any function that is managed in React
    editorInstance.model.change((writer) => {
      const imageElement = writer.createElement("image", {
        src: imageUrl,
      });
      // Inserting the image in the current selection location.
      editorInstance.model.insertContent(
        imageElement,
        editorInstance.model.document.selection
      );
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <button onClick={insertImage}> Insert Image from Media Library </button>
      <CKEditor
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        onReady={(editor) => {
          setEditorInstance(editor);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyEditor;
```

This is what I did in the above code:

- I saved the instant of the CKEditor in `onReady` event.
- I used the instance (`editorInstance`) in `inserImage` method.
- In `insertImage` method I got the image URL from a function.
- Then I inserted my desired content (here, an image) in the editor by using `editorInstance.model.change` and `editorInstance.model.insertContent`.